NeonDB Fetch Error with drizzleORM: Cannot connect to neon database from Next js 14 app to fetch data but connects for mutations
I'm trying to fetch data from my db in a server component but I keep getting this connection error
⨯ NeonDbError: Error connecting to database: fetch failed
at async page (./src/app/tailor-cv/job/[id]/page.tsx:18:17)
digest: "4084647856"

I don't know what the issue is, but I successfully made mutations to the same database in this same Next.Js 14 app. But the fetch calls seem to be having this connection error. Can anyone help me out

This is a screenshot from the console
